# WCF Byte Array - The maximum array length quota error

Tags: wcf

I am getting following error while returning byte array with WCF Service

"The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. 
This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 23626."

I even tried to increase the

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="EnrollmentSoapBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Also,

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
```

still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: To further help you, can you post both the server-end and client-end configs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your client and service have to have the `maxArrayLength` property set in their configurations.

You're obviously not setting it in one of them. As the default is 16384 for `maxArrayLength`.

Comment: That's possible - there are also other possibilities.  Hard to say unless OP posts the service model section of both configs.

Comment: @Tim Suppose Derek has a point. It is interesting to hear about other possibilities? Could you share some experience?

Comment: @voo - See my answer for a couple of other possibilities.

Comment: Sorry guys! The person who is consuming my service told me they he modified the client config. But no, after changing it everything works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Derek's answer, there are a couple of other possibilities the new value for `maxArrayLength` is not being picked up.

One is that the binding configuration has not been assigned to the endpoint.  For example, if the endpoint looks like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService1" />
```

Then the default values for `wsHttpBinding` will be used, regardless of what may be specified elsewhere in the config file.  To assign the defined binding configuration, use the `bindingConfiguration` attribute:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          bindingCongifuration="EnrollmentSoapBinding"
          contract="MyService.IMyService1" />
```

Another possibility is if there is no endpoint defined (in the service, at least).  In this case, the framework (in .NET 4.0 and later) will provide a default endpoint.  That default endpoint will use `basicHttpBinding` by default and have default values for it.

There are a few things that can be done in that scenario.  An endpoint can be explicitly declared and have the binding assigned to it (as shown in the first part of my answer).

The binding can be declared and set as the default by omitting the `name` attribute, like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

In this case, if there's no endpoint defined, you'd also need to change the protocol mapping for http:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/> 
</protocolMapping>
```

This would then set `wsHttpBinding` to be the default binding for `http`, and the "custom" default binding settings defined above would be used.

Without seeing both the service and client config, it's hard to say what the real issue is.